# MongoDB aggregation grouping fill missing values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB aggregation framework. I have a Mongo collection with documents like this:

```
{
  'step': 1,
  'name': 'house',
  'score': 2
}
{
  'step': 1,
  'name': 'car',
  'score': 3
}
{
  'step': 2,
  'name': 'house',
  'score': 4
}
```

I'm grouping the documents with same 'step' and pushing 'name' and 'score' into an array of objects. What I get is:

```
{
  'step': 1,
  'scores': 
  [
      {'name':'house','score':2},
      {'name':'car','score':3}
  ]
}
{
  'step': 2,
  'scores': 
  [
      {'name':'house','score':4}
  ]
}
```

For each 'step' I need to copy the value of previous 'step' in case that a 'name' does not exists. I should have something like this:

```
{
      'step': 1,
      'scores': 
      [
          {'name':'house','score':2},
          {'name':'car','score':3}
      ]
    }
    {
      'step': 2,
      'scores': 
      [
          {'name':'house','score':4},
          **{'name': 'car', 'score':3}**
      ]
    }
```

At the second document the element {'name':'car','score':3} has been copied from the previous document because at 'step:2' there is not documents having 'score' for 'car'.

I'm not able to figure out how to do this operation with MongoDB aggregation. Some help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What if step 1 do not have car record? and if step 3 have both scores, will it copy from there step 3? is it allow to get any of the step's car record means does not matter previous step it will take random step's car record? and what if house record is not available them it should be copy same as you said for car?

Comment: Hello, @turivishal, thanks for your interest.

Comment: @turivishal

- If step 1 do not have car record then step 2 should not have car record.
- When house is not available at step 2 it should be copied the same as I said for car.

I'll try to explain better the goal:

For each step, the two fields (house and car) should be inspected and in case that no value available for some of them, then missing value should be filled with the last value provided at previous steps. If no previous step has value for the field, then nothing to copy to current step.

Answer (score 0):

Required to use `$lookup` with pipeline, look below step by step,

- `$group` by `step` and push all scores in one array `scores`
- push all `name` in `names` of each score of particular step, we will use in match condition inside lookup

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$step",
      scores: {
        $push: {
          name: "$name",
          score: "$score"
        }
      },
      names: { $push: "$name" }
    }
  },
```

- `$unwind` `scores` because its array and we are going to lookup

```
  { $unwind: "$scores" },
```

- `$lookup` let variables `step`*(_id)* and `names` for pipeline level
- `$match` condition with expression `$expr` there are 3 conditions

  1. check the size of `names` It should be one`(1)`, either its `car` or `house`,
  2. match step number, it should be equal
  3. match `not in` for ex. if `car` is already available then it will search for `house` in lookup, need to use separate `$not` and than `$in`
- `$project` to show required fields
- lookup result will store in `clone_score`

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        step_id: { $subtract: ["$_id", 1] },
        names: "$names"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [{ $size: "$$names" }, 1] },
                { $eq: ["$$step_id", "$step"] },
                { $not: [{ $in: ["$name", "$$names"] }] }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: 1,
            score: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "clone_score"
    }
  },
```

- `$group` by `step`*(_id)* and push all scores in one array `scores`, keep first `clone_score`

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      scores: { $push: "$scores" },
      clone_score: { $first: "$clone_score" }
    }
  },
```

- from above pipelines, we have two separate array `scores` and `clone_score` now,
- `$project` we need to concat both of them in `scores`

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      step: "$_id",
      scores: {
        $concatArrays: ["$scores", "$clone_score"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fytf7NEU7uG